# decrementation and modulo - how to decrement negative value in one line of code

Tags: c++, modulo

I've found very gentle way to increment limited variable, just:

```
++i %= range;
```

Unfortunately this trick doesn't work for decrement, because `-1 % v == -1`.

How can I improve this in C++?

Comment: `i = (i + (range-1)) % range` should work for most ranges.

Comment: `++i %= range` causes undefined behaviour in C++03, this can be fixed by changing it to `i = (i+1) % range;`

Comment: I would also use `i = (i+1) % range;`
Can someone provide a reference to the standard for the undefined behaviour comment? (or elaborate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid the negative modulus behaviour you can just make it positive first:

```
i = (i - 1 + range) % range;
```

However this is no good if `range` is bigger than half of INT_MAX. (or whatever type `i` is).

This seems simpler:

```
i = (i ? i : range) - 1;
```

Comment: your second option isn't as compact as incrementation, but seems great, I'll give you accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want the same interval of [0, range), you just want to move through it in descending order.

It's rather complicated to do for an arbitrary period, but for powers of two (which needn't be constant), you can use

```
--i; i &= unsigned(range - 1);
```

which is analogous to the "optimization" of the positive version,

```
++i; i &= unsigned(range - 1);
```

One simple way way to do it for an arbitrary range is to use a second variable

```
++tmp; i = range - 1 - (tmp %= range);
```

Comment: `--i &= x` causes undefined behaviour in C++03 (not sure about C++11), writing to an object twice without intervening sequence point

Comment: @MattMcNabb: AFAICT in C++11 compound assignment `+=` and `&=` assert sequencing but prefix `++` and `--` do not.

Answer (score -1):

This code should work for decrementing `i` through the interval [0, range)

```
--i = (i > 0) * (i % range);
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour in C++03, writing to `i` twice without a sequence point. (C++11 introduced new sequencing rules, I'm not sure what the status of this is in C++11).